# How can I set the current date in the view in Drupal 7?

Tags: date, view, drupal-7

I installed the Date module.
So now I have field date.
In the views I want to set (as criteria) the current year.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it under filter settings for your view. 
Go to Filter criteria --> Add --> select your field --> select filter granularity (I guess it has to be a year)-- select operator (equal to) --> select "Enter relative date" and put "now" in the input field